# Particular judgment, general judgment, God's foreknowledge and free will

Tags: catholicism, judgment

My understanding of the relationship between particular judgement and general judgment is:

1. On particular judgement at the time of the death of the body, all our actions, thoughts and deeds will be judged and the soul will either continue to live in heaven, purgatory or hell. The full plan of God will not be revealed to us at this point nor the fate of all the other souls.
2. On general judgment every soul will be judged *publicly* according to their actions, thoughts, deeds **but also the consequences of his or her actions**. The Catechism of Trent writes:

> Those who depart this life sometimes leave behind them children who imitate their conduct, dependents,
> followers and others who admire and advocate their example, language and actions. Now by all these
> circumstances the rewards or punishments of the dead must needs be increased, since the good or bad
> influence of example, affecting as it does the conduct of many, is to terminate only with the end of
> the world. Justice demands that in order to form a proper estimate of all these good or bad actions
> and words a thorough investigation should be made. This, however, could not be without a general
> judgment of all men.

My question: Since at particular judgement the effects of my actions have not fully fructifed yet, **could the result of my particular judgement change at general judgment**, because not all consequences of my deeds are available at the point of my particular judgment?

This leads to the following questions:

a) If the answer is **yes**, a person who goes to heaven at particular judgment could go to hell after general judgement. This would be in conflict to the ex cathedra teaching of papal bull *benedictus deus* (https://www.papalencyclicals.net/ben12/b12bdeus.htm), which states:

> And after such intuitive and face-to-face vision [of the divine essence] and enjoyment has or will have begun for these souls, the same vision and enjoyment has continued and will continue without any interruption and without end until the last Judgment and from then on forever.

So, from my understanding, a person which goes to heaven after particular judgment **is guaranteed to stay in heaven** after general judgment.

b) If the answer is **no**, which I think is the doctrinal answer under the light of *benedictus deus*, the **judgment of God at particular judgment already accounts all the consequences of my deeds**, even though they are not fructified yet. This implies that **God has absolute foreknowledge**, which is in conflict with the **free will of the person**.

So the final question is:

**How do you reconcile the judgment at particular judgment, which implies absolute foreknowledge of God with respect to the consequences of my actions, with the free will of the person?**

I'm interested in the Catholic viewpoint on this question. Please give references to doctrinal documents whenever possible.

Comment: Your "final question" (which has been discussed here before in several places) is different from "What's the relationship between particular judgment and general judgment?" Which question are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you @Geremia, I have edited the title.

Comment: absolute foreknowledge doesn't conflict with free will. God is eternal (outside time) and observes all moments of time simultaneously. To know something will occur does not mean God causes it to occur. See Boethius on the Consolation of Philosophy for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the question:

> could the result of my particular judgement change at general judgment, because not all consequences of my deeds are available at the point of my particular judgment?

We must answer "No" as you infer from Benedictus Deus, which leads to your final question:

> How do you reconcile the judgment at particular judgment, which implies absolute foreknowledge of God with respect to the consequences of my actions, with the free will of the person?

The foreknowledge of God intrinsically does not impact free-will.

God is eternal (Summa I Q10 A2), time being a creation of His, and ever moment of time is observed simultaneously by God (Summa I Q10 A1). Boethius in Book V of the Consolation of Philosophy elaborates on this "If you should wish to consider [God's] foreknowledge... you will more rightly judge it to be not foreknowledge as it were of the future but knowledge of a never-passing instant." He then indicates we speak not of "prevision" but "providence" because God from afar looks upon all things "as though from the highest peak of the world" (VI). Thus foreknowledge imposes no necessity upon action. Our choices are known by God and so He does know the effect as well, but He didn't cause us to chose any particular outcome.

If we had no free-will, punishment and reward would be meaningless as well.